# how to send email when maxretries reached in nservicebus MSMQ

Tags: .net, msmq, nservicebus

I have a .net service that processes messages. For any failures, i use log4net and write to a file. I added an SMTP appender for this. The issue is that I only want to send one email when something goes wrong. The MaxRetries in my app.config is set to 5 and this is correct, 5 errors are logged in the log4net file but 5 emails are also sent.

Is there some way I can get a handle on the max retries and fire my email when that is reached?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a regular nservicebus endpoint that reads from the error queue. Add a handler for IMessage and within that handler add a call to smtpclient.send.

I have a post that tries to explain error handling for message based systems that might be of interest:
http://andreasohlund.net/2010/03/15/errorhandling-in-a-message-oriented-world/

Hoep this helps!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. I already use smtpclient send however, the issue is that 5 emails are sent if the max retries is set to 5. I want to send only one email regardless of how many retries are carried out.

Comment: That's why you should monitor the error queue and only send the emails when messages are put there. Messages will be put in the error queue after all configured retries has been performed. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ah, the penny drops. Thanks for that, i'll have a look.

Cheers.

Comment: Ok, here's how I understand it:
- You have an endpoint watching the error queue for specific message types
- Upon receiving said message type, you do something like sending an email or notification
At that last point, doesn't the message get taken off the error queue so it can't be returned to it's source queue?

Comment: Configure that endpoint to audit to a "final" error q: <UnicastBusConfig ForwardReceivedMessagesTo="error_final"/>

Comment: Also take a look at the new Monitoring support that is beeing built, that will do all this for you:https://github.com/NServiceBus/Management